# How to use dataProvider for testing POST API with Rest-Assured

Tags: api, post, dataprovider, rest-assured

I am using Rest- Assured to test API.
I have the following test, that I want to iterate over with varying post parameters

given()
                .parameters("param1", "abc",
                        "password", "1234",
                        "param3", "abc")
                .when()
                    .post("Login")
                .then()
                    .statusCode(400));
    }

How would I do that?

Comment: You are still searching answer ?

Answer (score 1):

To start over with the post parameters, try sending them using MAPs in the form of Key Value pair. This way out you can dynamically create your own JSON Body. After that in given() function, pass the Content type as JSON and pass the jsonAsMap in Body.

```
    Map<Object, Object>  jsonAsMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    jsonAsMap.put("param1", "abc");
    jsonAsMap.put("password", "1234");
    jsonAsMap.put("param3","abc");

        RestAssured.given()
            .log().all()
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(jsonAsMap)

        .when()
            .post("http://DomainName/Login") . //Pass the link of the POST URL
        .then()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .assertThat()
                .statusCode(400);
```

Since you would be using JUnit so , this will work, In case if you are using TestNG framework, you can shift to Data Provider. In you scenario, this above mentioned could be a better way to test the status for certain POST Request.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to read the inputs from a file and to pass it to the parameters() method. (We are using that to read our inputs from a json file)

Or if you are using TestNG, you can use its dataprovider also.

Hope it helped you.